# Prevent CSS inheritance to children of the selected element

Tags: css, css-cascade

I have a menu consisting of nested ULs and LIs, eg:

```css
.wrapper > ul:first-child > li:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolar</li>
    <li>Style me!
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Don't style me!</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a style to the last `<li>` of the first `<ul>`, but not have it's children (the nested `<ul>`) inherit it.

I have tried:

```css
.wrapper > ul:first-child > li:last-child {/*styles*/}
```

but this still styles the last element.

Would anyone know how I can target just that 1 element (with just CSS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some CSS properties are [inherited](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#inheriting) and you can't prevent that.

> *Inheritance* propagates property values from parent elements to their children.
>
> Some properties are *inherited properties*, as defined in their
>   property definition table. This means that, unless the cascade results
>   in a value, the value will be determined by inheritance.

However, you can override that by selecting the children and restoring the desired value.

```css
.wrapper > ul:first-child > li:last-child {
  color: red;
}
.wrapper > ul:first-child > li:last-child > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolar</li>
    <li>Style me!
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Don't style me!</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```